# How to create an array of strings by using array module?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm new to Python programming. I'm reading Arrays in Python and when I want to create an array in Python, I need to import this module array.

For integers I write like this : `('i',[1,2,3])`
For floating I write like this : `('d',[1.1,2.3])`

Now I need to create an array like this for example `['A','B','C']`. How could I create it by using the array module?

Comment: Are you sure you want an array? Lists are generally better for string elements unless you *know* all the elements are going to be, say, one character, or three, or some other fixed width.

Comment: @Linuxios I know about the list, dear Sir. But I wanted to know if it is possible by using this module.

Comment: Great -- I just wanted to make sure that the information on lists was here on the question for others who come across it later who might not know. It looks like Jack's answer below answers about `array`. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) state that it's used for:

> Efficient arrays of numeric values

However I think the `u` (Unicode character) will suffice for your needs

```py
("u", ["A", "B", "C"])
```

It would be generally better to make a standard Python list, though:

```py
myList = ["A", "B", "C"]
```

Because this means you aren't bound by any restrictions on what data type your array could contain.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but why it gave me the results like this? array('u', 'abvccd')

Comment: Because I believe it's for a *series* of Unicode characters - see the link to the documentation for an example.

Comment: OK, dear Sir. Thank you so much. :)